# How to use true, false and both condition in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a check box in my design (Active). It stores either 0 or 1. I have to search items on the basis of check box value, ie., either active or inactive or both. For active I can use 1 and for inactive I can use 0. But I need to use all the condition (true,false,true and false).

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume:

- you have 0 for inactive, 1 for active in your column
- you pass 0 for inactive, 1 for active and 2 for both as parameter `@active`

Now change your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
-- Active is the column name and @active is the query parameter
WHERE {existingConditions} AND (@active = 2 OR @active = Active)
```

UPDATE:

Since you didn't add the appropriate tags, I will base my answer on both windows forms and WPF for UI and ADO.NET for data access. For the other technologies you can use approaches similar to this.

For winforms: Let's say your `CheckBox` has its `ThreeState` property (`IsThreeState` in WPF) set to `true`, then you can get and pass the value like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = conenction.CreateCommand();
sbyte active;
switch (checkBox1.CheckState)
{
    case CheckState.Checked:
        active = 1;
        break;
    case CheckState.Unchecked:
        active = 0;
        break;
    case CheckState.Indeterminate:
        active = 2;
        break;
}

/*
// For WPF:
if (checkBox1.IsChecked.HasValue)
    active = checkBox1.IsChecked ? 1 : 0;
else
    active = 2;
*/
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", active);
```

Comment: Be careful here. If you have defined the active parameter as a bit and pass in a 2 and the value the engine will turn that into a 1. declare @ active bit = 2;select 'whoa' where @ active = 1;

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I will update the answer to clarify this matter :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you already have a `WHERE` statement with `SomeConditions` you are checking then you would simply do this:

For active...

```
WHERE SomeConditions AND Active = 1
```

For inactive...

```
WHERE SomeConditions AND Active = 0
```

For either...

```
// Just leave the Active out of the WHERE statement
WHERE SomeConditions
```